# Sfml collision: when the player hits a square, he just stops moving

Tags: c++, sfml

I decided that I wanted to make a collision test in c++ and sfml. But when the player hits the square you can't move anymore. I'm not having any issues with how to do collision, but what to do when I actually GET a collision.

Here's my code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

RenderWindow window(VideoMode(500, 500), "SFML");

RectangleShape r1;
RectangleShape r2;

void collision(){

r1.setSize(Vector2f(50.0, 50.0));
r2.setSize(Vector2f(50.0, 50.0));

r1.setPosition(20, 200);
r2.setPosition(420, 200);

r1.setFillColor(Color::Red);
r2.setFillColor(Color::Blue);
}

int main(){

collision();

while (window.isOpen()){
    Event event;

    while (window.pollEvent(event)){

        if (event.type == Event::Closed){
            window.close();
        }
    }

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W))
            if (!r1.getGlobalBounds().intersects(r2.getGlobalBounds()))
                r1.move(0.0, -0.05);

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A))
            if (!r1.getGlobalBounds().intersects(r2.getGlobalBounds()))
                r1.move(-0.05, 0.0);

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::S))
            if (!r1.getGlobalBounds().intersects(r2.getGlobalBounds()))
                r1.move(0.0, 0.05);

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D))
            if (!r1.getGlobalBounds().intersects(r2.getGlobalBounds()))
                r1.move(0.05, 0.0);

    window.draw(r2);
    window.draw(r1);

    window.display();
    window.clear();
}
}
```

Once again, I would like to know how to properly move your player and make it so that when you can't enter a object.

Thanks in advance!

PS. Please don't tell me "uh, your code is so horribleee. your bracketss suck ablahb..." I know. It's a little messy alright?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem at Jack Edwards's answer is intersection control is before move command. But firstly sprite must move and after comes intersection control. If there is intersection, sprite must move back.

```
if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W)){
                r1.move(0.0, -0.05);
            if (r1.getGlobalBounds().intersects(r2.getGlobalBounds()))
                r1.move(0.0, +0.05);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're only allowing your player to move if its bounds don't intersect with the bounds of the second object, so when you first collide with the object you can no longer move outside of it bounds.

What you need to do is move the player back when it collides with the object.

For example:

```
if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W)) {
    sf::FloatRect& intersection;
    if (r1.getGlobalBounds().intersects(r2.getGlobalBounds(), intersection) {
        r1.move(0.0, intersection.height);
    }
    else {
        r1.move(0.0, -0.05);
    }
}
```

The intersects method allows you to pass in a reference to a sf::Rect, and if the player's bounds intersects with the second object's bounds, the intersection will be stored in the rect.

This allows you to move the player back by the required amount of space so that the objects will no longer be intersecting and the player can move again.

Comment: It still doesn't work! The player just freezes! Or it works, but not always.

Comment: Okay, so I found out that why the player gets stuck sometimes is because he goes inside the cube. And when he does that, pressing any walking key will eject him elsewhere. How do I make him not enter the cube?